# Creating a new Pandas column from different substrings found in two other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a large csv file containing real estate information in columns like:
items=

```
 {0: "[5 Bedrooms','25.00 sq mt']",
 1: "['1 Bathroom', '64.00 sq mt']",
 ...
```

and features =

```
{0: "['Shops: Close by', 'Passing trade: Yes']",
 1: "['Lift: Yes', 'No of Bedrooms: 1', 'Bedroom 1 Dims: 10.00 x 10.00 mt', 'No of Bathrooms: 1', 'Dining Room Dims: 5.00 x 9.00 mt', 'Kitchen Dims: 1.00 x 1.00 mt combined', 'Living Room Dims: 1.00 x 1.00 mt combined', 'Terrace (Front): Yes', 'Has Views: Excellent Town views', 'Type of View: Town views', 'Finish: Very Good', 'Shops: Within walking distance', 'External Area: 5.00 sq mt', 'Total Area: 64.00 sq mt']"}
```

I want to create a new column from the number of bedrooms in each property. I can either get it from the features column using

`csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Features'].astype(str).extract('No of Bedrooms: (\d+)')`

or from the items column:

`csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedroom')`

or `csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedrooms')` if there is more than 1 bedroom.

I want to write a script which tries to find the number of bedrooms from the features list and if the number is not included try in the items list. I tried something like this but it did not work (I am a rookie in dataframes and indexing).

```
if csvname['Features'].astype(str).extract('No of Bedrooms: (\d+)') !=0:
   csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Features'].astype(str).extract('No of Bedrooms: (\d+)')
elif csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedroom') !=0:
   csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedroom')
else:
   csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedrooms')
```

The result of the first two rows should be

```
{0: 5,
{1: 5,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
s1 = csvname['No of Bedrooms']=csvname['Features'].astype(str).extract('No of Bedrooms: (\d+)')
s2 = csvname['Items'].astype(str).extract('(\d+) Bedroom')

csvname['No of Bedrooms'] = s1.fillna(s2)
```